# Momentum conceptual question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws

[image]

The answers for the questions are as follows:

Part I. speed of the cart stays constant.
Part II. momentum decreases.
Part III. KE increases.

For Part I, I am not sure why would the speed would increase. I thought the speed would decrease because the mass would decrease. If momentum is conserved in the horizontal direction, we can let initial momentum
$= MV$ and final momentum $= M'V'$.

$$MV=M'V'$$

Since the cart was losing water, $M>M'$, $V'>V$.

Answer (score 1):

Part 1:

Presumably no vertical momentum is transferred to any horizontal momentum.

I. The speed should decrease - You can imagine it as if the ice blocks are hitting the train head on. Clearly that should slow the train down.

II. The momentum should stay constant - The momentum of the whole system should be conserved.

III. Kinetic energy will decrease (Assuming that the ice blocks stay in place once dropped in the train)

Part 2:

I. The speed should stay constant - Nothing is happening to make the train speed up or slow down.

II. Momentum will decrease - The momentum of the whole system is conserved but the momentum of the train will be less because it does not include the momentum of the ice/water anymore.

III. Kinetic energy will decrease - Less mass and same speed equals less kinetic energy.

Comment: The system is the melted ice water and the train. Since, the railroad is frictionless and there is no air resistance, as the water leaves the train the water loses no momentum.  It would simply keep moving along with the train beneath it. So the system (water and train) conserves all it's momentum.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: Yes. Momentum is not conserved for the railroad cart because the water leaves. But it is conserved if you include the water and the cart.